# BigQuery data transfer Job failed with error INTERNAL (Error: 80038528)

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I have created a table in BQ and went ahead and made a cloud storage data trasfer job (ref - https://cloud.google.com/bigquery-transfer/docs/cloud-storage-transfer). But the job is throwing the following error.

```
Job bqts_6091b5c4-0000-2b62-bad0-089e08e4f7e1 (table abc) failed with error INTERNAL: An internal error occurred and the request could not be completed. Error: 80038528; JobID: 742067653276:bqts_6091b5c4-0000-2b62-bad0-089e08e4f7e1
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason of the job failure with (Error: 80038528) is not enough slots being available. With respect to resource allocation, there is no fixed resource availability guarantee when using the on-demand model for running queries in BigQuery. The only way to make sure a certain number of slots is always available is by moving to a flat-rate model [1].

If slot is not an issue, then you can follow what @Sakshi Gatyan as mentioned. That is the right way to get an exact solution for BigQuery internal error.

[1]. https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/slots

Comment: Similar issues with cross region data copy using data transfer.  The job was working fine, until suddenly it failed.  Not sure of slots can be the issue as transfer works for same region movement of data.  Wondering if there has been any policy changes related to cross-region data transfer.

Answer (score 1):

Since it's an **internalError**, there can be multiple reasons for your job failure depending upon your environment.

[check error table](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/error-messages#errortable)

The job needs to be inspected internally by the Google support team. So I would recommend filling a [case](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/manage-cases#creating_cases) with [support](https://console.cloud.google.com/support).